# Simple second order ODE in Scilab

Tags: differential-equations, scilab

I am very new to scilab and am trying to understand how ODE works for second order ODE works in SCILAB.

My Equation is:
(d^2y)/(dt^2 )+2 dy/dt + y=0

I would like to plot the results.
So far I have understood I need to break down the equations in to two first order equations. So the program must look like:

```
function dx=f(x, y)
    dx(1)=2*y+1;
    dx(2)=y;
endfunction
```

Can you check if this is correct, I am not sure if `dx(1)` and `dx(2)` is correct.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If x_1 is y and x_2 is dy/dt you would rather write your ode right hand side (i.e. dx/dt) like this

```
function dxdt=f(t, x)
    dxdt(1) =  x(2);
    dxdt(2) = -x(1)-2*x(2);
endfunction
```

Comment: I am getting an error. Undefined variable: x. It says at line 2 of function f.

Comment: Ok the error is because of y0 values, they must be in the form y0=[%pi;1]. Can you explain why?

Comment: Having the rhs is not enough. Please learn by yourself a bit of Scilab by reading the help page od `ode`, now that you have the correct function for your ode.